# Selecting previous rows using a condition (lag?)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My dataframe structure is one row per study day, starting at day 0. There are 47 different participants differentiated by studyID. On some days, participants have a swab taken, this is marked by a 1 in column "swabbed". Some of these swabs have already been selected for further analysis based on other criteria, this is marked by a 1 in column "selected".

I do not need to process all of the swabs so I am trying to write code that will choose which of the currently unselected swabs (swabbed = 1, selected = 0) should be processed. Criteria: for each participant, assess each row, if swabbed = 1 and selected = 0 and that sample was taken 10 to 21 days after the last row where swabbed = 1 and selected = 1 then mark this as selected (= 1) in a new column called selected_new, otherwise mark as not selected (selected_new = 0). I would like these assessed sequentially i.e. if one row meets the criteria, this becomes the new, most recent selected sample so may mean subsequent rows now do not fulfill the date criteria.

Below is an example df, only includes one participant. In this example, row 14 (day = 13, date = 2022-11-30) meets the criteria so would be selected_new = 1. Therefore  row 18 (day = 17, date = 2022-12-04) does not meet the criteria as it was only 4 days after row 14 which was just selected.

```
df <- data.frame(
  studyID = c("SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001","SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001", "SAC001"),
  day = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19),
  date = as.Date(c("2022-11-17", "2022-11-18", "2022-11-19", "2022-11-20", "2022-11-21", "2022-11-22", "2022-11-23","2022-11-24", "2022-11-25", "2022-11-26", "2022-11-27", "2022-11-28", "2022-11-29", "2022-11-30","2022-12-01", "2022-12-02", "2022-12-03", "2022-12-04", "2022-12-05", "2022-12-06")),
  swabbed = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  selected = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"))
```

I have tried to achieve this by first creating a column that calculates the number of days since the last selected sample by using lag with the sample date but I'm not clear if a condition can be applied to lag e.g. lag(date[selected == "yes"]). Then I can do a if_else to check if its in the range of 10-21d, not shown this part below as the first part isnt working i.e. the days_since_last_selected is way off.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
     last_selected_date = lag(sample_date[selected == "yes"]), 
     days_since_last_selected = if_else(swabbed == 1 & selected == 0, sample_date - last_selected_date, NA))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you say "assessed sequentially", you will need to use rolling windows, using either `zoo::rollapply`, `slider::` (several funcs), or `data.table::frollapply`, or you can adapt `Reduce`/`purrr::accumulate` for the same effect.

Comment: @tlo can you produce the desired output? It's kinda hard to follow what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want something like this:

```
swab_dates <- function(d) {
  last_date = d[1] # this assumes that each study starts with a selected swab
  selected = c(1, rep(0, length(d)-1))
  for (i in seq_along(d)[-1]) {
    if (between(as.numeric(d[i] - last_date), 10, 21)) {
      selected[i] = 1
      last_date = d[i]
    }
  }
  return(selected)
}
df |> 
  mutate(patient_id = 1,
         selected = as.integer(selected)) |>
  filter(swabbed == 1)|>
  mutate(selected = swab_dates(`date`), .by = c(studyID))
```